# PostgreSQL scoring distance with trigrams

Tags: postgresql, levenshtein-distance, trigram

I would like to understand why the distance between 2 words is so big with just a letter reverse.

Example:

```
SELECT name, searchable, searchable <-> 'fluerie' AS dist FROM shd_appellations WHERE region_id=3 ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1;
```

Result:

```
fleurie => 0,6666666
```

So, the distance is 0,666 between ***fluerie*** and ***fleurie*** ! I know the word is truncated into *"flu", "lue", ... "rie"* before comparing but I need to set a limit in my code and I fix it to 0.5 maximum distance to obtain a result... so in this case the matching is not taken.

I could set a max distance of 0.75... but I don't want to match other terms not related to search in some other cases.

An idea: could it be logical to increase the distance for small words, so depending search term width ?